# Updating Preference UI instance from another activity?

Tags: android, android-preferences

How do i update a Prefence UI instance that i created in a Setting Activity from another activity (Main Activity)?

I tried using these lines in Main Activity to update the Preference within Settings Activity,  but I get `ClassCastException`.

```
Preference IsFeature =(Preference)((PreferenceActivity)context).findPreference((getString(R.string.key_enable_feature)));
IsFeature.setEnabled(True);
```

Just wondering whether theres another way to do this?

Any help, feedback or answers would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

In xml of settings get the "key" attribute from element you want to change (in bottom example it's "example_switch"). Than put this code in onClick method of button or wherever else you want to. This below takes the preference of switch in general settings and sets its value to false.

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
editor.putBoolean("example_switch", false); // "example_switch" - "key" attribute of your element | false - value
editor.commit();
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that worked! Really appreciate it!